# Kotlin how to get and open a video

Tags: android, file, kotlin

New to Kotlin and i'm trying to simple get any video from gallery and open into device's default app player.

My function to get all videos. It seens to work well, but the returned Uri is like 'content://...', i don't know if this is the right or it should be something like 'file://...'

```
private val videos = mutableListOf<Uri>()

private fun getAllVideos() {
    val uriExternal = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)

    contentResolver.query(uriExternal, projection, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val videoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriExternal, "" + cursor.getString(0))
            videos.add(videoUri)
        }
    }
}
```

Then i try to open the Uri like this, but i always get an error from the player and nothing works.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = videos.first()
    type = "video/*"
}

startActivity(intent)
```

I searched but dont found any updated tutorial that don't use "MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA" (it's deprecated now). Something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the returned Uri is like 'content://...', i don't know if this is the right

Yes, it is.

> Then i try to open the Uri like this, but i always get an error from the player and nothing works.

First, either remove the `type` or use the correct MIME type. Do not use a wildcard.

Second, add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`. Without it, the other app has no rights to access the content.

Also, make sure you only go through that code if there is at least one element in the list, as otherwise your `first()` call will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks. "type" was causing the error. Removed it and now everything works fine. (even without the flag).

Comment: @ThiagoYou: I still recommend adding the flag. Do not assume that another app necessarily has access to the content. But, I am glad that you have it working!